# Contiki-NG RE-Mote board: The radio is always listening

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng

I wanted to measure the energy consumption of my app using energest. However, I found out that the radio is almost always listening, as the RX energest value is pretty close to the Rtime interval I measure about. I want to ask you if I should use low-power-mode in the board, so that I force the radio to deactivate and result in less energy consumption. Can I use PM0 if I really need to use the RAM? I am asking you because the linker puts a comment in a header file that only PM1 can give access to the 32k RAM, and bypasses the defined macro: #define LPM_CONF_MAX_PM  0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the CSMA MAC protocol is used in Contiki-NG. This protocol always has radio on. For radio duty cycling, either use TSCH, or turn off the radio from application's code by calling `NETSTACK_RADIO.off()`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work just fine. Thank you!